# How can I prevent automatic linkifying in a Markdown table?

Tags: html, hyperlink, markdown

Markdown automatically turns valid HTML links into links, eg. `http://example.com` becomes http://example.com.

(You can try this out by, for example, raising an issue in a github repo, typing in the `http://example.com` and then looking at the "preview" tab - since github uses markdown.)

When markdown encounters an HTML tag, it stops this behavior, eg. `<div>http://example.com</div>` stays just `http://example.com`.

However, it seems that if you use `<div>`s in a markdown table, then it starts automatically linkifying again, eg. if you type:

`|Parameter|Value|
|-------|-------|
|Date |Tue Jan 01 1980|
|Parameter|<div>http://example.com</div>|`

you'll see http://example.com is a link.

I am using [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it), but as I mentioned, it also happens with github's markdown.

How can I prevent this automatic linkification in markdown tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most reliable way to prevent Markdown from parsing content is to wrap it in a code span. Some would even argue that a plain text URL should always be wrapped in a code span:

```
Some text with a URL: `http://example.com`.

|Parameter|Value|
|-------|-------|
|Date |Tue Jan 01 1980|
|Parameter|`http://example.com`|
```